# Why arc with angles given by "trig format=rad" gives wrong result?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[trig format=rad,red]  (0:1) arc(0:pi:1);
\draw[blue] (0:1) arc(0:180:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why red and blue arc are not the same?

[image]

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, oh, this warning is on the next side of description of the `trig format` ... I didn't turn page to see it :-( . Is there any chance that it will left "experimental" status and become full operational?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `\pgfpatharc` macro of the PGF level that is used by TikZ to draw the arc is working with degrees as it is using the number 90 in some places:
As with any non-straight line in PGF/TikZ, an arc will be converted to a Bézier curve and the control points are orthogonal to the given angles where the number 90 will be used. This seems to be the reason why you don't even get an arc but a parabola of some kind. (At some other points the `tan` function or `\pgfpointpolar` will be used which should work correctly with radians.)

The manual also warns that this might happen

> At the time of this writing, this feature is “experimental”. Please handle it with care: there may be path instructions or libraries in PGF which rely on `trig format=deg`. The intended usage of `trig format=rad` is for local scopes – and as option for data visualization.

This seems to be one of the cases.

---

I'd suggest always using degrees in the case of `arc`, in this simple case you can use the `r` postfix operator without any troubles:

```
\draw[red, dashed, thick] (0:1) arc(0:pi r:1);
```

Though, the `arc ()` syntax is deprecated for a long time and it should be:

```
\draw[green, dashed] (0:1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=pi r, radius=1];
```

Here you can also use the `deg()` functions without having to protect the `)`.

---

Nonetheless, I propose a small fix by letting `\pgfpatharc` convert everything to degrees and work only in degrees.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\pgfpatharc{\pgfutil@in@}{%
  \pgfmathiftrigonometricusesdeg{}{%
%    \typeout{\pgf@temp@a, \pgf@temp@b}%
    \pgfmathradians@{\pgf@temp@a}\let\pgf@temp@a\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathradians@{\pgf@temp@b}\let\pgf@temp@b\pgfmathresult
%    \typeout{\pgf@temp@a, \pgf@temp@b}%
    \def\pgfmath@trig@format@choice{0}% \pgfset{trig format=deg}
  }\pgfutil@in@}{}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[trig format=rad, red]  (0:1) arc(0:pi:1) % check if timer is correct:
  node foreach \p in {0,.125,...,1} [pos=\p, sloped, scale=.3, below] {\p};
\draw[red, dashed, thick] (0:1) arc(0:pi r:1);
\draw[green, dashed] (0:1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=pi r, radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: wow! +1 for now, since I need to some time to figured out your solution :-)

Comment: Nice. Maybe it should be reported to Ti*k*Z project?

Comment: There is (I think) another report of this [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690780/non-circular-tikz-arc). Should I open an issue on https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues or do you want to make the honors? ;-)

Comment: @Rmano Just opened https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1270, Full/More operational `/pgf/trig format=rad`