# Non-circular TikZ arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need help drawing a circular arc in TikZ as mine is shaped like a balloon. Thanks!

Edit: I don't care where the arc is, I just want it to be circular and almost 2pi radians (to indicate the axis of rotation), like the one in this post from a helpful comment by rmano: [Why arc with angles given by "trig format=rad" gives wrong result?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685949/why-arc-with-angles-given-by-trig-format-rad-gives-wrong-result/685953#685953)

I've resolved the issue by converting from radians to degrees. Thank you all for your help.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
    axis line style = thick,
    trig format=rad,
    enlargelimits,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    enlarge y limits=0.15,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south east}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[standard]
\addplot[color=white]{x};
\draw[] (0,0) arc [start angle=0.1*pi, end angle=1.9*pi, radius=1];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please check the pgfplot manual, section about adding tikz-statements to pgfplot. Not sure, but perhaps the distortion comes from ignoring relevant conditions.

Comment: As I read the question (and its title) the TO wants a circle in the neg. x-axis, but the result is unexpected. // If so: please clarify, see answers below.

Comment: @  MS-SPO, you may right. Frankly said, this was not entirely clear what OP is after. For any case, I would add circle on negative axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't figure yet why but the issue vanishes when you use degrees instead of radians. And of course you'll have to use `axis equal` if you want to see a perfect circle and not a bumped one.

[image: circle arc in pgfplots]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
    axis line style = thick,
    %trig format=rad,
    enlargelimits,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis equal,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    enlarge y limits=0.15,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south east}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[standard,disabledatascaling]
\addplot[color=white]{x};
\draw[blue] (axis cs:0,0) arc [radius=1,start angle=0.1*180, end angle=1.9*180];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/685953/38080. Somebody should open an issue on GitHub... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, for the particular graph in question I'll use trig format=deg in the options

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure the question is clear enough. What is the mathematical context of the question. Do you mean Lemniscate or eight curve?

If so, you should use the formulae available, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate

If not, here is a suggestion with plain TikZ: just use `controls`

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={angle=30;force=5;}]
\clip (-5,-2.5) rectangle (5,2.5);
\draw[line width=1pt,magenta]
(0,0) .. controls +(180-angle:force) and +(-180+angle:force) .. cycle
(0,0) .. controls +(angle:force) and +(-angle:force) .. cycle;  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I read the question (and its title) the TO wants a circle in the neg. x-axis, but the result is unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
    trig format=rad,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis equal,
    xmin=-6.2, xmax=6.5, 
    ymin=-6.2, ymax=6.5, 
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[standard]
\draw[blue, very thick] (0,0) to [out=0.75*pi,in=1.25*pi, loop, min distance=54mm] (0,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Now I see, that I may misunderstood your question. In the case, that you like to draw circle with center on the negative x axis, than solution can be simple, without use of `arc` instruction::

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{
standard/.style={
trig format=rad,
axis lines=middle,
axis equal,
xmin=-6.2, xmax=6.5,
ymin=-6.2, ymax=6.5,
}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[standard]
\draw[blue, very thick] (-2.7,0) circle[radius=2.7];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

[image]

However, if you persist to draw it with `arc7 than see [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685949/why-arc-with-angles-given-by-trig-format-rad-gives-wrong-result/685953#685953).

Comment: As I read the question (and its title) the TO wants a circle in the neg. x-axis, but the result is unexpected.